# Hide inherited member in client project

Tags: .net, inheritance

I have an interface with a method `Validate()` and an abstract class that implement this interface, and made a class called `CustomerValidator` that inherit the abstract class, also have entity `Customer` inherit `CustomerValidator` so i can call `customer.Validate()` in the library project.

my scenario is that i dont want the validate method to be available on the client code..if they new up a customer they should only see the entity properties..ex fistname ect. How do i hide the validate method? Thanks

Comment: What language? What platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must also ask why `Customer` inherits `CustomerValidator`, but also why is `CustomerValidator` abstract? I would suggest you change your interface and implementation as follows:

```
public interface ICustomerValidator {
    void Validate(Customer customer);
}

public abstract class CustomerValidator : ICustomerValidator {
    public abstract void Validate(Customer customer);
}
```

Then, if you insist on being able to do something like

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.Validate();
```

I would suggest you use [C# extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) like this:

```
public static class CustomerExentions {
    public static ICustomerValidator CustomerValidator { get; set; }

    internal static void Validate(this Customer c) {
        if(CustomerValidator == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("CustomerValidator cannot be NULL");
        }

        CustomerValidator.Validate(c);
    }
}
```

Note the `internal` scope so that clients cannot use this call.

As for using composition, I don't think `Customer` should know anything about `CustomerValidator` or `ICustomerValidator`. Those external responsibilities are outside the scope of a `Customer` class. If anything, `CustomerValidator` can have a `Customer` property if you insist on using composition, but I think the interface should take in a `Customer` parameter instead.

Comment: hi i like the idea of composition makes more sense. But how to check if an entity is of type IentityValidator(which customervalidator implement thru the abtract class entity validator?

Comment: my abstract class is generic so that all entities use it.

Comment: might be doing this wrong but here is the part in the extension metthod i created for the ObjectStateEntry(EF): dynamic entity = entry.Entity;
            IEntityValidator BusinessRuleValidator = entity as IEntityValidator;
            if (BusinessRuleValidator != (IEntityValidator)null)
            {
                  BusinessRuleValidator.Validate(instance,result);
            }

Comment: Your extension method actually sounds better idea. Can you do one extension for all entities?

Comment: You can't use an extension method like this if you're going to use composition cuz your class would have to be static in order to implement the extension method, but would also have to implement ICustomerValidator in order to properly use composition. But a static class cannot implement an interface. I know composition is easier to understand, but for what you're trying to do, I think my proposed solution makes the most sense and is actually easier to use and using composition yields other problems. Please take another look at my post and try to understand it. Let me know what's confusing you.

Comment: Just saw your question. Yes, you can use an extension for all entities as long as the extension is something like Validate(this Entity entity) assuming Customer : Entity.

Comment: Actually the BusinessRuleValidator.Validate() is a call to the validate method in the IEntityValidator interface, so be like public abstract partial class EntityValidator<TEntity,E> : IEntityValidator where E:struct where TEntity:class ,new() and CustomeValidator implement  EntityValidator which has the attachvalidation method and validate. The reason why i put validate in interface so that i can make that call if entity is IEntityValidator.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use a good design, but keep in mind that good design incorporates proper code separation. Your Entity class should be in a common namespace of your model layer, and your business rule validators should be in their own namespace of a business logic layer. I stress one more time that Entity should not know anything about business rules and that any validators should be separate from the Entity class (and its inheriting children).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inheritance, use composition.

Why does your `Customer` class inherit from `CustomerValidator`? It is **not** a `CustomerValidator`, is it?

You can have a private `CustomerValidator` field in your `Customer` class - you can call `Validate` on it.

My example is in C#, though the principle applies to Java and other OOP lanaguages:

```
// I would use DI of some sort to decouple the classes. This is just illustative
private CustomerValidator cv = new CustomerValidator(); 

// Somewhere else in the customer class:
cv.Validate(this);
```

Comment: It inherit from CustomerValidator because I am adding validatin rules inside CustomerValidator. Here is the signiture: public class CustomerValidator : EntityValidator<Customer, CustomerRuleSet> { public CustomerValidator() { AttachValidation(.... ); } }

Comment: I can also i add more validation as needed, and the implementation of AttachValidation is in the abstract class so all entities would take advantage of it. That's why i put it as absctract..common funtionality to all entities.

Comment: I am also using inheritance to check if entity is of type IEntityValidator which CustomerValidator implement(entityvalidator implement IentityValidator. I am looping thru the ObjectStateEntry of entity framework doing validation right before savechanges().

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a slightly different way how to organize your classes. The part you want the client to know about (the class "customer") contains all seeable properties. Internally in your lib you use wrapper classes that include the customer entity. So your librabry works with a full set of methods, using the wrapper classes that include the customer class but have more methods, and the client passes the costumer class to your lib which wraps it before continueing.

Answer (score 0):

I know Customer is not a CustomerValidator ..maybe the name makes a little confusion, but in my case i have the Customer implement the CustomerValidator where the validation rules gets added in the constructor and keep the Customer class clean. But I found the answer to my question, so what i did is Implement the Interface where the validate method is Explicitly. So on the client code validate is not visible in the Customer entity.

Comment: I'm glad you got your code working, but I still respectfully disagree with putting that logic into your Customer class. Again, the customer class should not be aware of business rules unless they are general and enforced via contracts. It also defeats the purpose of having an ICustomerValidator in the first place. Either way, good luck.

Comment: I agree with you, i was satisfied with the framework i set up , up untill the need to figure out how to tie each entity to its corresponding validator type in the last minute before savechanges(). I overrided the savechanges method to have validation of all attached entities. So kinda hard to know which entity beign validated when I am looping thru the ObjectStateEntry, my code needs to be able to figure out which entity and then add validation rules for that entity, go validate and add to the results and so on..

Comment: Be nice to have something cleaner. I will mark my answer as correct because that took care of the question beign able to hide validate from the developer coding client code.

Comment: Well, my answer is a cleaner approach, and it works...it is a bit advanced but I was willing to help you through it. It would've also been nice to receive some credit for my efforts already...